# ggplot geom_bar doesn't show all data frame subsets plotted

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a gggplot barplot that has in x axis a genomic start position and y axis a value for height.

I have a table with 3000 lines and I am trying to plot subset of it like:

```
ggplot(data = chr1[1:4,c(1:3,9,14)]) +
    geom_bar(aes(x= start,y=V7), stat="identity")
```

This part of the table looks like this

```
dput(chr1[1:4,c(1:3,9,14)])
structure(list(seqnames = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1"), 
    start = c(858042L, 858076L, 5955119L, 5955150L), end = c(858192L, 
    858155L, 5955238L, 5955257L), V7 = c(22.74576, 8.52652, 10.04841, 
    7.32666), which = c("sorted", "rep3", "rep3", "sorted")), row.names = c(1707L, 
1L, 2L, 1708L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
     seqnames   start     end       V7  which
1707     chr1  858042  858192 22.74576 sorted
1        chr1  858076  858155  8.52652   rep3
2        chr1 5955119 5955238 10.04841   rep3
1708     chr1 5955150 5955257  7.32666 sorted
```

I get an empty plot in that case, the plot shows on my device but I don't get any bars.

Then if I try on plotting the first subset like

```
ggplot(data = chr1[1:2,]) +
    geom_bar(aes(x= start,y=V7), stat="identity")
```

I get the bars normally.

If I use fill or color I get all the bars as well as you can see in the next question below.

Why could that be?

Additionally, I would like to plot all my bars, without using factor(start) and use a transparent fill with alpha (column which) so as I can see them when they are falling really close. The alpha factor doesn't seem to get applied without factor in the x axis.

For example this

```
ggplot(chr1[1:4,], aes(x=start, y=V7, fill=which, color=which)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",alpha=0.2) + theme_minimal()
```

gives me the bars but no transparency applied

Is there a workaround this one?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is your `start` column numeric? If so, you are visualising bars spread out of million units away from each other, that'd be too thin for you to see it.

Comment: It is numeric, yes. I want to check the position of all those starts based on the rep and if I apply a factor I just see them next to each other so I miss the proximity of their positions.

Comment: I am still not getting anything. And actually those 10 start positions are very close pairwise so I would expect to see for example the first two/first four at least if it was a problem of them being too far away right?

Comment: No. Imagine you place a needle on the ground and view it millions of miles away, you just won't be able to see it, no matter you have 4 needles together or what, unless you have a really really huge needle. To get a huge needle, play around with the `width` parameter in `geom_bar` or `geom_col`

Comment: But then I see them when I add fill and color parameters. Doesn't that mean that this is where the problem could be as well?

Comment: If you posted your test data using `dput`, not only would it be easier for us to help you, but you wouild immediately see if `start` (and other columns) were numeric or not.

Comment: I have edited my question with dput and a shorter example, thank you.

Comment: I have just run the code with your updated data frame, and @benson23 is correct. If you include `width = 1000000` to `geom_bar` then you will see the bars. You will get a warning because in order to make the bars wide enough to be visible, they will so wide that the first two bars and the last two bars overlap, so it will be difficult to tell you have four bars. You might want to consider using vertical line segments instead of bars, or using a categorical x axis instead.

Comment: Thank you. Seems like indeed I need some other representation overall probably because visually it will not be very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)
```

To illustrate the issue with having `start` as numeric.

```
example_df <- data.frame(start = seq(1, 30, 1)^3,
                         V7 = runif(10, 5, 25))

p1 <- ggplot(example_df[1:5, ], aes(x = start, y = V7)) + 
  geom_col() +
  ggtitle("First 5")

p2 <- ggplot(example_df[1:20, ], aes(x = start, y = V7)) + 
  geom_col() +
  ggtitle("First 20")

p3 <- ggplot(example_df, aes(x = start, y = V7)) + 
  geom_col() +
  ggtitle("All")

p4 <- ggplot(example_df, aes(x = factor(start), y = V7)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45)) +
  ggtitle("As factor rather than numeric")

p1 + p2 + p3
```

[image]

```r
p4
```

If you instead made `start` into a factor they will have similar spacing.
[image]

If however the distance between the bars is important you need to fiddle with the `width` argument.
But you run the risk of having bars overlapping each other.

```r
ggplot(example_df, aes(x = start, y = V7)) + 
  geom_col(width = 200)
#> Warning: `position_stack()` requires non-overlapping x intervals
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>